# Merge two greps into single one

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to extract an ID from the output of another command. Currently my extracting command looks like:

```
someID=$(command | grep -oP '(?:^Successfully\sbuilt\s)([\da-z]{12}$)' | grep -oP '([a-z\d]{12})')
```

Example command output:

```
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b4624927fa6
Successfully built 9b4624927fa6
```

Expected result:

```
9b4624927fa6
```

ID extracted from line

```
Successfully built 9b4624927fa6
```

How could I merge those two grep statements into single one?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Your command seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: If you are building a docker image, you can give it a name with the `--tag` option. That way, you can supply the name instead of having to parse it from the output. Also, `--quiet` supresses all output except for the image ID.

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes, but they want to combine the two `grep` calls into a single command.

Comment: @Sjoerd oh thanks for suggestion, will definitely try it, I need that id exactly for this reason, want to build simple automated pipeline for docker containers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slight modification of your first `grep` works for me:

```
$ grep -oP '^Successfully\sbuilt\s\K[\da-z]{12}$' example-output
9b4624927fa6
```

[`\K` in PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#resetmatchstart) resets the match start:

> The escape sequence `\K` causes any previously matched characters not to
>   be included in the final matched sequence.

It's similar to a zero-width positive look-behind assertion  `(?<=Successfully...`).

Comment: `\K` is not a look behind assertion, it just sets the start of the matched text here reported by `-o`. Compare `echo aaaaa | grep -Po 'a\K.'` with `echo aaaaa | grep -Po '(?<=a).'` (this time using a look-behind assertion).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: To be fair, `perlre` describes it in the same list item as positive look-behind assertions, with language and typography that strongly suggests thinking of one as a variant of the other (even though that can't be the case at a technical level).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes, it's unfortunate. The `pcrepattern` man page does not make that confusion. It's true `\K` can often be used in place or positive look behind assertions.

Answer (score 7):

To get the hexadecimal number at the end of a line that starts with `Successfully built`, I would probably use `sed`:

```
sed -n -E 's/^Successfully built ([[:xdigit:]]+)$/\1/p'
```

This replaces the matching line with the hash and prints it (and no other line).

Or `awk`:

```
awk '/^Successfully built [[:xdigit:]]+$/ { print $NF }'
```

This prints the last whitespace-delimited field of each line matching the regular expression.

In both regular expressions, the `[[:xdigit:]]+` expression will match a non-empty string of hexadecimal digits.